# Bug in std::from_chars when type is int8_t and base=2

Tags: c++, c++17

`std::from_chars` fails with a generic error when parsing a string of bits (base=2) as a signed 8-bit integer, whereas `std::stoi` parses the signed 8-bit integer without error.

Both blocks in the program below parse the same string of bits. The program ends by calling `std::abort` on the first assertion in the second block. `std::stoi` parses the same string of bits without error.

```
// Compile: g++ -std=c++17 -O0 -g main.cc -o main
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <charconv>
#include <cstdint>

int main()

{
    {
        std::string bits = "10011100";
        int base = 2;
        std::int8_t num = std::stoi(bits.c_str(), nullptr, base);
        assert(num == -100);
    }

    {
        // Bug found in std::from_chars when type is int8_t and base=2.
        std::string bits = "10011100";
        int base = 2;
        std::int8_t num;
        auto [ptr, ec] = std::from_chars(bits.data(),
                                         bits.data() + bits.size(),
                                         num,
                                         base);
        assert(ec == std::errc()); // Calls std::abort.
        assert(num == -100);
    }
}
```

Output of running this program after compiling with `g++ -std=c++17 -O0 -g main.cc -o main`.

```
# ./main
main: main.cc:24: int main(): Assertion `ec == std::errc()' failed.
Aborted
```

Comment: Is the error `result_out_of_range`?

Comment: Printing the message with `std::make_error_code(ec).message()` gives `Numerical result out of range`. The explanation is that `std::from_chars` does not interpret the bits as two's complement when the type is signed integer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`10011100` in binary is `156` in decimal.

A signed 8-bit integer type is not able to hold that value (maximum is `127`) and therefore `std::from_chars` will fail.

It doesn't fail for `std::stoi`, because the value `156` is in range of `int` (which is at least 16bit wide).

---

If your intention is to interpret the bits as a two's complement representation of an 8bit integer value, then you need to first parse it into a `uint8_t`, then cast to `int8_t`, assuming that the C++ implementation also uses two's complement to represent `int8_t`. This is mandatory in C++20, but not C++17. If the implementation does not use the same representation as what you want to parse represents, then you need to do the conversion manually.

Comment: My intention was to parse as two's complement 8-bit integer. I thought this would not overflow since the two's complement value (-100d) is within the range of a signed integer -128 <= x <= 127, but now I know not to assume the parser will interpret the bits as two's complement. Thank you!